# RxJS Buffer or Buffer Size Limit

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I need `buffer` functionality with output size limiting.  Say I have an observable stream `myInterval` which I want to gate the output of using a notifier observable `bufferBy`, but when the notifier fires I want to limit the number of items emitted.  `buffer` doesn't have an overload like this, but it illustrates what I'd like to achieve.

```js
const maxBufferSize = 5;
const myInterval = interval(1000);
const bufferBy = fromEvent(document, 'click');

const bufferedInterval = myInterval.pipe(buffer(bufferBy, maxBufferSize));

// ex. output: [1,2,3] ... [4,5,6,7,8] ... [9,10]
```

Should be lossless. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Maybe just like this?**

[window](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/window) operator

```
const maxBufferSize = 5;
const myInterval = interval(1000);
const bufferBy$ = fromEvent(document, 'click');

myInterval.pipe(
  window(bufferBy$),
  mergeMap(bufferCount(maxBufferSize)),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/szp6ke

Comment: really creative approach :) good job

Comment: I update my  Answer, maybe use `window` operator.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the current RxJS operators are not able to do this. But it is not difficult to write our own operator with the wanted behaviour.

```js
function bufferWithSize(bufferBy, maxBufferSize) {
  return (observable) =>
    new Observable((subscriber) => {
      let buffer = []

      // whenever bufferBy emits, we also emit the whole buffer to the subscriber
      const bufferBySubscription = bufferBy.subscribe(() => {
        subscriber.next(buffer)
        buffer = []
      })
      
      const subscription = observable.subscribe({
        next(value) {
          // when the source emits, we push the value into the buffer
          buffer.push(value)

          // if we reach the maxBufferSize, we emit the whole buffer
          if (buffer.length === maxBufferSize) {
            subscriber.next(buffer)
            buffer = []
          }
        },
        error(err) {
          subscriber.error(err);
        },
        complete() {
          // emit the rest of the buffer when the source completes
          if (buffer.length > 0) subscriber.next(buffer)
          subscriber.complete()
        },
      });
 
      return () => {
        // clean up subscriptions when bufferWithSize is unsubscribed
        subscription.unsubscribe();
        bufferBySubscription.unsubscribe()
      };
    });
}
```

Usage:

```js
const maxBufferSize = 5;
const myInterval = interval(1000);
const bufferBy = interval(3000) // change this to 8000 to see the maxBufferSize in action

const bufferedInterval = myInterval.pipe(
  bufferWithSize(bufferBy, maxBufferSize)
).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this would work:

```
const bufferedInterval = bufferBy.pipe(
  concatMap(() => myInterval.pipe(
    takeUntil(bufferBy),
    bufferCount(maxBufferSize),
  ))
);
```

The idea here is, we start with your `bufferBy` trigger. `concatMap` subscribes to `myInterval` and emits it's values until the `bufferBy` observable emits OR until the `maxBufferSize` has been reached.

If you don't want to wait for the trigger to initially emit, you can add in a `startWith()`:

```
const bufferedInterval = bufferBy.pipe(
  startWith(undefined),
  concatMap(() => myInterval.pipe(
    takeUntil(bufferBy),
    bufferCount(maxBufferSize),
  ))
);
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-74378196?devtoolsHeight=65&file=index.ts) demo.

Comment: Ah good to see that there is also an approach without a custom operator :)